# How to pass a parameter to different methods on single call, eliminate passing the same parameter every time?

Tags: c#-4.0, tdd

I have TDD Sql database project setup and calling `Assert` method definition

```
Assert.AreEqual(someObject.GetValue<int>(Constants.SomeValue),
    anotherObject.GetValue<int>(dt, Constants.SomeValue), "some message")
```

Question : i need to pass `Constant.SomeValue` to `GetValue` method for each call. How can we eliminate this. Can we define this in outer method ( i.e `Assert` ) so that method refrenced inside takes the parameter value. i can create an extension method on string class but then again i need to pass all object and build assert method and return from extension method.Any Ideas on this or an easy approach.

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please provide a sample of what you want the code to look like.

Comment: let me elaborate more on this, i am passing object params to Assert method by calling GetValue(string) method. The GetValue params are const string defined in class, these string are hardcoded datatable column name. I am asserting on value from testContext datarow and datable from source (TDD). You can see Constant.SomeValue need to be passed whenever a call is made to GetValue() method. Can we define it somewhere where ( like in Assert or anynymous) so that it should get refrenced inside.

Comment: Again: Please provide the code the way you want to use it.

Comment: Something like this :-
AssertHelper.Execute( (Constant.Name) => Assert.AreEqual(this.GetValue<string>(---Constants.Name should be used here--), ds.GetValue<string>( ---Constants.Name should be used here--), Constants.Messages.PortfolioName));

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure of what you're getting at.

Looks like you're leaning towards a new helper method for assertions. Isolate the common parts into the helper method and only pass in the parts that differ across calls as parameters to the method.

```
public void PleaseNameMeBetter<T>(Constants columnName)
{
   Assert.AreEqual(someObject.GetValue<T>(columnName),
                   anotherObject.GetValue<T>(dt, columnName), 
                   "some message")
}
```

Comment: I prefer type-safe constants as opposed to strings.. less fragile. define each constant as `public static readonly ColumnX = new Constants();`